# Import high-resolution images from a PDF?

Tags: import, image, pdf-format

I have a [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12B_aduDOQxo2MjGQNy3-zuO2kRh7V6Os/view?usp=sharing) that I want to resize after importing.
However, ImageResize doesn't seem to take into account the high-resolution of the initial image, and resizing makes it very pixelated. I can rescale the original import by hand for better effect, but how can I get this result automatically?

```
G0 = Import["Structure.pdf"][[1]];
Style[Grid[{{G0, ImageResize[G0, Scaled[2]], G0}}],ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image: Original import, image resize, and manually resized original image]

Comment: Please make that link to the image a 1-click download such that no sign-on to any service is required. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what site I can use to upload a pdf that way.

Comment: Link to google drive with sharing enabled?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have changed it.

Comment: I guess, you should add the option `"PageImages"` into `Import` command. This will give you the full-scale images instead of the thumbnails

Comment: It looks like you use a *Mathematica* version lower than 12.2, so you should use the last solution from my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should use the `"EmbeddedImages"` element when importing raster images from a PDF file:

```
Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/article.pdf", "EmbeddedImages"]
```

From the Documentation:

[image: screenshot]

But your file "Structure.pdf" doesn't contain raster images - it is a pure vertor figure. Hence if you wish to convert it to raster, you can use the `"PageImages"` element with either `ImageResolution` or `"RasterSize"` option for controlling the resolution of the final raster image:

```
Import["Structure.pdf", {"PageImages", 1}, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
Import["Structure.pdf", {"PageImages", 1}, "RasterSize" -> 500]
```

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, you can import it as a vector figure, and then use `Rasterize` to convert it to a raster image:

```
vectFig = Import["Structure.pdf", If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, {"PDF", "Pages"}]][[1]]
Rasterize[vectFig, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, this works!